# Having some trouble with click event inside map

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase

I'm retrieving events from Firebase and I want to show a list of them with buttons saying 'subscribe' if the person is not subscribed to it, or 'unsubscribe'. That's where I'm having issues.

I added a click event to every `btn-primary` button and I check if the button that was clicked has the class `btn-danger`. If it has then remove it, if not then add it.

It was supposed to run only one time, but I put a `console.log` inside of it and it's printing the amount of events retrieved and it's subscribing to all events instead of subscribing only to the one the person clicked it. It's inside of a `map()`.

```js
eventos.map(async function(evento) {
  ref = firebase.database().ref("eventos-usuarios/" + evento.id).child(user.uid);
  dados = await ref.once("value");

  botaoAzul = "<button value='" + evento.id + "' class='btn btn-primary text-uppercase font-weight-bold'> Me inscrever <span class='fas fa-user-plus'></span> </button>";

  botaoVermelho = "<button value='" + evento.id + "' class='btn btn-primary text-uppercase font-weight-bold'>Cancelar inscrição <span class='fas fa-user-times'></span>";

  tabela += "<div class='row mb-5 bg-light'>" +
    "<div class='col-12'>" +
    "<h2>" + evento.titulo + "</h2>" +
    "</div>" +
    "<div class='col-12'>" +
    "<img src='" + evento.caminho + "' class='img-fluid'>" +
    "<span class='fas fa-calendar'></span> " + evento.data + "<br>" +
    "<span class='fas fa-clock'></span> " + evento.horario +
    "</div>"
    + "<div class='col-12'>" +
    evento.descricao +
    "</div>"
    + "<div class='col-6 pt-2 teste'>";

  dados.val() ? tabela += botaoVermelho : tabela += botaoAzul;

  tabela += "</div>" +
    "<div class='col-6 pt-2'>" +
    "<button class='btn btn-success text-uppercase font-weight-bold'>" +
    "Compartilhar <span class='fas fa-share-alt'></span>" +
    "</button>" +
    "</div>" +
    "</div>";

  $(".container").append(tabela);

  $(".btn-primary").on("click", function() {
    console.log("cc");
    if ($(this).hasClass("btn-danger")) {
      $(this).removeClass("btn-danger");
      $(this).html("Me inscrever <span class='fas fa-user-plus'></span>");
    } else {
      ref = firebase.database().ref("eventos-usuarios/" + evento.id + "/" + user.uid);
      ref.set({
        uid: user.uid,
        nome: user.displayName
      }).then(() => {
        $(this).addClass("btn-danger");
        $(this).html("Cancelar inscrição <span class='fas fa-user-times'></span>");
      }).catch(erro => Notificacao.erro(erro));
    }
  });

  tabela = "";
  $("#img-loading").removeClass("mx-auto, d-block");
  $("#img-loading").css("display", "none");
});
```

Comment: Move the `$(".btn-primary").on("click", function() {` block **outside** of the loop. You're creating multiple events on every `.btn-primary` element

Comment: if I move it to outside i' lose the reference for each event

Comment: In which case add `evento` to the `data()` held in `.btn-primary` element and then read it out when the click happens.

Comment: it worked, thanks a lot man

Comment: Izaac, please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) so you know what's expected of you next. I'm sure Rory will be providing his suggestion as an answer shortly.